# parse String date to long java

Tags: string, parsing, date, long-integer

I have a `String date = dd/MM/yyyy`. How can I parse it to long? Have I to get the day, parse to long, get the month, parse to long, get the year, parse to long and then concatenate?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to get the `long` as the concatenation of ddMMyyyy, or the number of milliseconds between epoch and the `Date` represented by this `String` ?

Comment: I need the date in format long to insert it in Google Calendar intent

Comment: So, I think that you need a number of milliseconds from epoch, as given in @Jens answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Date string with Time to long date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305048/convert-date-string-with-time-to-long-date)

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting. This topic has been handled in hundreds of Questions and Answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Formatter to parse the date:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy");
Long date = df.parse("12/12/2014").getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

using simpledateformat you can easily achieve this

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

     String currentDate = "01-March-2016";
     SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
     Date parseDate = f.parse(currentDate);
     long milliseconds = parseDate.getTime();
}
}
```

for More information click [Here](https://qamanual.blogspot.in/2016/06/how-to-convert-string-date-into.html)